# Implementing CountDownTimer properly

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I am currently developing a game for the Android OS. In it, the player can carry out activities. Each activity costs the player "energy". The players current energy value is stored in an sqlite table and displayed on the home screen(home.class). When the player carries out activities, the energy value will decrease. When the energy reaches zero, i want a countdown timer to reset the energy value to 10.

The way I have implemented it so far is as follows. At the top of the main screen that displays the users health/energy ratings I have displayed the CountDownTimer.

The timer works. However, when I click a button and go to a different activity..and then return to the Home screen, the timer has restarted. I know this is because the following code runs when I want to return to the home screen:

`Intent i = new Intent(Crime.this, Home.class);
        startActivity(i);`

It starts a new Home.class because i want to update the values displayed in the Home screen after some activities have been carried out.

What is a better way to implement the CountDownTimer? Any help would be appreciated...thanks :)

Comment: Could you add a refresh() type method to the Home class and call that instead of making a new instance?

Comment: You mean something like this? 
`public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();  
   Home h = new Home();
   h.refresh();`

Answer (score 0):

store the time at which you want to reset the energy in the database (at least once you hit `onPause`) and update the remaining time with a ticking thread thing. That way you don't need to rely on timers to finish / restart since you can always recalculate the times based on e.g. the current system time